# Write expectation of brownian motion conditional on filtration as an integral?

Tags: brownian-motion, martingales, conditional-expectation

Let $W=(\Omega,{\cal F},P)$ be the probability space of Brownian motion. Let $V=\Omega \rightarrow {\mathbb R}$ be the signature of random variables.  Let $B_t(\omega)$ be a time-indexed family of random variables which are Brownian motions.    $B$ has signature $B: {\mathbb R}^+ \rightarrow V$. Let $X:V$. Define by Lebesgue integral the *expectation* ${\mathbb E}_{W} X=\int_{\omega \in \Omega} X(\omega) d P(\omega)$. So ${\mathbb E}_W: V\rightarrow {\mathbb R}$.
Let $(X \star Y)(\omega)=X(\omega) Y(\omega)$.  Let ${\cal G} \subseteq {\cal F}$.  Define, by *implicit* construction, the *conditional expectation* $Z={\mathbb E}_W(X|{\cal G})$, as the random variable $Z:V$ such that for all $A \in {\cal G}$, ${\mathbb E}_W(Z \star {\mathbb 1}_A) = {\mathbb E}_W(X \star {\mathbb 1}_A)$.  Let ${\cal F}_t \subset {\cal F}$ be the natural filtration of $B_t$. Can we show, by *explicit* construction, that ${\mathbb E}_W(B_t|{\cal F}_s)(\omega)=B_s(\omega), 0\leq s\leq t$?

Comment: Sorry but I fail to understand your question. You know that $E(W_t/mid\mathcal F_s)=W_s$, what more are you seeking?

Comment: In the [discrete case](http://www.math.nyu.edu/faculty/goodman/teaching/StochCalc2011/book.pdf), $E[X|B]=\sum_{\omega\in B} X(\omega)P(\omega|B)$.  So I am looking for the analogous continuous case where you replace the sum with an integral and $B$ with  ${\cal F}$.

Comment: Then $$E(W_t\mid\mathcal F_s)=\int_0^sdW_u\ ?$$

Comment: Hi Did, that works.  Doesn't give me a general expression though.  Let me rephrase as "A Lebesque or Ito integral in the continuous case analogous to the sum in the discrete case of $E[X|B]$", where X is some unknown random expression, not just $W_t$.   Do you get the gist?

Comment: No. My impression is that you have no question here... but please prove me wrong.

Comment: Did, I was satisfied to the answer [here](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/36618/write-expectation-of-brownian-motion-conditional-on-filtration-as-an-integral/36622#36622).

Comment: Cool. So you were actually asking for the conditional *distribution*? If so, let me suggest to make yourself **much** clearer next time (and of course, avoid crossposting).

Comment: No, I was asking for conditional expectation translation from compact notation $E(W|F)$ into something more constructive/computational involving some kind of integrals (Ito, Lebesgue, Riemann), corresponding to the translation of $E(X|B)$ in the discrete case into sums over the event space of $B$.  Also, I cross-post because I am asking naive learner-level questions and I find that where I get unconstructive negative feedback on one site, I get constructive and helpful feedback on another, where the disciplines of the sites intersect but the perspective on another site is more conducive.

Comment: Yeah, you keep repeating this, which, sorry to say, makes little sense. No big deal.

Comment: To my understanding, $E(W|F)$ is an expression for an expectation, not an expression for a distribution.

Comment: Indeed. Conditional distributions were mentioned in a (failed, it seems) try to make sense of your question, which, if one stays at the level of conditional expectations, has none. (Unrelated: I see that you try to justify cross-posting. On this, one can be brief: **Don't do that, period.**)

Comment: "I find that where I get unconstructive negative feedback on one site, I get constructive and helpful feedback on another" Maybe you find yourself clever by posting such jabs but whether you do or not, please know that this settles the matter for me. Yes, in a negative way.

Comment: It's not a jab.  Different sites come with different bodies of experience and ways of thinking about things.  You have done nothing to educate me about why my question is ill-posed.  Another person on a different site was, in my view, more constructive and informative.  I will continue cross-posting questions where I think I will get that benefit.  If you have a problem with this, then please escalate and maybe there's a mechanism on this site for you to get my account removed or blocked.

Comment: Cross-posting is [frowned upon](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu) on the network. Please don't do that.

Answer (score 0):

(**NOT AN ANSWER YET, JUST NOTES.**  *This is the start of an answer to my question as posted, not an answer.  Go ahead and downvote if you want.  I'm not putting this in the statement of the question because it's going to be the answer, not the question.*)

#### $\sigma$-algebra

Let $\Omega$ be a set.  A $\sigma$-*algebra* in $\Omega$ is a nonempty collection ${\cal G}$ of subsets of $\Omega$ such that

- $\Omega \in {\cal G}$
- If $A \in {\cal G}$ then $\Omega-A \in {\cal G}$
- If $(\forall n \in {\mathbb N})\, A_n \in {\cal G}$, then $\cup_{i=1}^\infty A_i \in {\cal G}$

#### $\sigma$-algebra generated by a family of subsets of $\Omega$

Let $H$ be any family of subsets of $\Omega$.  The unique smallest $\sigma$-algebra which contains every set in $H$, written $\sigma(H)$, is called the $\sigma$-*algebra generated by* $H$.

#### Measurable set

A pair $(S,\sigma(S))$ of a non-empty set and its $\sigma$-algebra is called a *measurable space*. a member $T \in \sigma(S)$ is called a *measurable set*.

A function $f:S\rightarrow T$, where $(S,\sigma(S))$ and $(T,\sigma(T))$ are measurable spaces is said to be $(\sigma(S),\sigma(T))$-*measurable* if for all $B \in \sigma(T)$ then $f^{-1}(B) \in \sigma(S)$. The set of real-valued measurable functions is called ${\cal L}^0$. [Zitkovic](https://www.ma.utexas.edu/users/gordanz/notes/measurable_spaces.pdf)

#### Measure

$\mu:{\cal F}\rightarrow {\mathbb R}$ is a *signed real-valued measure* in the measurable space $(\Omega,{\cal F})$ iff for any sequence of disjoint sets $\{A_n\}_{n=1}^\infty \in {\cal F}$, $\mu(\cup_{n=1}^\infty A_n) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty\mu(A_n)$.

A function $\mu$ is a *measure* iff $\mu(A)\geq 0$ for all $A \in{\cal F}$, and then we say $(\Omega,{\cal F},\mu)$ is a *measure space*.  The measure $\mu(A)$ defines an integral of a nonnegative measurable function $f(\omega)$ by

$$\int_{\omega\in\Omega} f(\omega) d\mu(\omega) = \lim_{h\rightarrow 0} \lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{n=0}^N n h \mu(\{\omega \in \Omega: nh \leq f(\omega) \leq (n+1) h\})$$

#### Probability measure

A positive measure $P:{\cal F}\rightarrow[0,1]$ such that $P(\Omega)=1$ is called a *probability measure*.

#### Lebesgue integral, ${\cal L}^1$

Let $f\in{\cal L}_+^{Simp,0}$.  The *Lebesgue integral*
$$\int f d\mu = \sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_k \mu(A_k) \in [0,\infty)$$
where
$$f=\sum_{k=1}^n \alpha_k {\mathbb 1}_{A_k}$$ is a simple-function representation of $f$.

Let $f\in{\cal L}_+^0([0,\infty])$.  The *Lebesgue integral*

$$\int f d\mu = \sup \{  \int gd\mu: g \in {\cal L}_+^{Simp,0}, g(x) \leq f(x), \forall x \in S\} \in [0,\infty]$$

Let $f^+=\max{(f,0)},f^-=\max{(-f,0)}$.  A function $f\in{\cal L}^0$ is said to be *integrable* if $\int f^+ d\mu < \infty$ and $\int f^- d\mu < \inf$.  The collection of all integrable functions in ${\cal L}^0$ is written ${\cal L}^1$. [Zitkovic](https://www.ma.utexas.edu/users/gordanz/notes/lebesgue_integration.pdf)

#### Brownian trajectories and events

The space $\Omega$ of *elementary events* for Brownian motion is the set of all continuous real functions $\Omega = \{\omega: {\mathbb R}_+ \rightarrow {\mathbb R}\}$.  We refer to the $\omega(t)$ as *Brownian trajectories*.

A *cylinder set* of Brownian trajectories for a finite set of times $0\leq t_1<t_2<\cdots<t_n$ and real intervals $I_k=(a_k,b_k),1\leq k \leq n$ is constructed as

$$C(t_1,\ldots,t_n;I_1,\ldots,I_n)=\{\omega\in \Omega: \forall\,1\leq k \leq n: \omega(t_k) \in I_k\}$$

The space of *Brownian events* ${\cal F} \subseteq 2^\Omega$ consists all sets of Brownian trajectories obtained from cylinders by operations of countable unions, intersections and complement.  ${\cal F}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra of $\Omega$:

$${\cal F}=\sigma(\{C(t_1,\ldots,t_n;I_1,\ldots,I_n): n \in {\mathbb Z}^+: 0\leq t_1<\cdots<t_n, I_k=(a_k,b_k),1\leq k \leq n\})$$

By definition, the elements of ${\cal F}$ are measurable sets.

#### Weiner probability measure

Let the *Weiner* probability measure $P$, where $I=(a,b)$ and $0=t_0<t_1<t_2<\cdots<t_n$ and $I_k,1\leq k\leq n$ are real intervals, be:

$$P(C(t;I))=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi t}}\int_a^b e^{\frac{-x^2}{2 t}} dx$$

$$P(C(t_1,t_2,\cdots,t_n;I_1,I_2,\ldots,I_n))=\int_{I_1} \int_{I_2}\cdots\int_{I_n} \prod_{k=1}^n \frac{dx_k}{\sqrt{2\pi(t_k-t_{k-1})}} \exp\big(-\frac{(x_k-x_{k-1})^2}{2(t_k-t_{k-1})}\big)$$

#### Brownian motion probability space

The [probability space of Brownian motion](http://www.springer.com/cda/content/document/cda_downloaddocument/9781441916044-c1.pdf?SGWID=0-0-45-855433-p173940722), $W=(\Omega,{\cal F}\subseteq 2^\Omega,P:{\cal F}\rightarrow [0,1])$.

#### Brownian motion

Let $B_t(\omega)$ be a time-indexed family of random variables which are Brownian motions.    $B$ has signature $B: {\mathbb R}^+ \rightarrow V$. Let $X:V$.

Then *mathematical Brownian motion* $B_t(\omega) = \omega(t)$ is an infinite family of random variables  $B:{\mathbb R}_+ \rightarrow V$ for which, in the Brownian motion probability space $W$,

1. $B_0(\omega)=0$ with probability 1
2. $B_t(\omega)$ is almost surely a continuous function of $t$
3. $\forall t,s \geq 0$, the increment $\Delta B_s(\omega)=B_{t+s}(\omega)-B_t(\omega)$ is independent of ${\cal F}_t$ is a zero mean Gaussian random variable with variance ${\mathbb E}|\Delta B_s|^2 = s$.

#### Random variable

A *random variable* $X(\omega) \in (\Omega, {\cal F}, P)$ is a real function $X:\Omega \rightarrow {\mathbb R}$ such that ${\omega \in \Omega : X(\omega) \leq x} \in {\cal F}, \forall\,x \in {\mathbb R}$.  Write $V=\Omega \rightarrow {\mathbb R}$ for the signature of random variables and write $X:V$.

#### Topology

A *topology* on a set $S$ is a family $\tau$ of subsets of $S$ which contains $\emptyset$ and $S$ and is closed under finite intersections and countable or uncountable unions.  The elements of $\tau$ are called *open sets*.  The structure $(S,\tau)$ is called a *topological space*.

#### The topology of real numbers

Let ${\cal O}$ be the set of all open sets $(a,b)$ where $-\infty < a < b < \infty$.  Then $({\mathbb R},{\cal O})$ is a topology of real numbers.

#### Borel $\sigma$-algebra

If $(S,\tau)$ is a topological space, then $\sigma(\tau)$, generated by all open sets, is called the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $S$.

#### Borel algebra on the reals

$${\cal B}({\mathbb R}) = \sigma({\cal O})$$

#### $\sigma$-algebra generated by a random variable

Let $X$ be a random variable.  The $\sigma$-*algebra generated by* $X$ is

$$\sigma(X) = \{X^{-1}(A) : A \in {\cal B}({\mathbb R})$$

#### Expectation

A real-valued integral in $W=(\Omega,{\cal F},P)$ of a random variable $X(\omega)$ with respect to probability measure $P$ is called an *expectation* and written

$${\mathbb E}_W X=\int_{\omega \in \Omega} X(\omega) d P(\omega)$$

The signature is ${\mathbb E}_W: V \rightarrow{\mathbb R}$.

#### Indicator function

For any set $A\in\Omega$, the *indicator* of $A$ is a random variable defined as

$${\mathbb 1}_A(\omega) = \cases{ 1 & if $\omega \in A$\\  0 & otherwise }$$

The signature is ${\mathbb 1}: {\cal F} \rightarrow \Omega \rightarrow \{0,1\}$.

#### Multiplication of two random variables

Let $(X \star Y)(\omega)=X(\omega) Y(\omega)$.

#### Event which is an atom

Let $\mu$ be a measure. A set $A \subseteq \Omega$ is called an *atom* if $\mu(A) > 0$ and for any measurable subset $B \subset A$ with $\mu(B) < \mu(A)$, $\mu(B) = 0$.

#### Atoms of a random variable

Let $Y$ be a random variable.  The *atoms of* $Y$ are

$${\cal A}(Y) =\{\{x : Y(x) = a\}: a \in Y^{-1}(\Omega)\}$$

*TBD*: Show that each element of ${\cal A}(Y)$ is an event which is an atom.

#### Conditional expectation

**Conditional expectation: Implicit construction**

Assume we are working in $W=(\Omega,{\cal F},P)$.  Let

- ${\cal G}$ be a $\sigma$-algebra contained in ${\cal F}$
- $X$ be a random variable
- $Z$ be ${\cal G}$-measurable

Define the *conditional expectation of* $X$ *with respect to* ${\cal G}$, written $Z={\mathbb E}_W(X|{\cal G})$, to be a random variable $Z\in {\cal L}^1$ such that [Zitkovic](https://www.ma.utexas.edu/users/gordanz/notes/conditional_expectation.pdf)

- $Z$ is ${\cal G}$-measurable
- For all $A \in {\cal G}$, ${\mathbb E}_W(Z \star{\mathbb 1}_A) = {\mathbb E}_W(X \star {\mathbb 1}_A)$.

This definition of ${\mathbb E}_W(X|{\cal G})$ is *implicit*.  The signature is ${\mathbb E}_W(X|{\cal G}):V$.

**Conditional expectation: Explicit construction in discrete case**

Let's look at an example from [Zitkovic](https://www.ma.utexas.edu/users/gordanz/notes/conditional_expectation.pdf) in the finite domain for insight that may lead us to an explicit construction for ${\mathbb E}_W(X|{\cal G})$:

Let $W=(\Omega,{\cal F},{\mathbb P})$ where $\Omega=\{a,b,c,d,e\}$, $F=2^\Omega$ and ${\cal P}$ is uniform.  Let $X=\{a\mapsto 1,b\mapsto 3,c\mapsto 3,d\mapsto 5,e\mapsto 5,f\mapsto 7\}$, $Y=\{a\mapsto 2,b\mapsto 2,c\mapsto 1,d\mapsto 1,e\mapsto 7,f\mapsto 7\}$.  Let ${\cal G}=\sigma(Y)$. Then $Z={\mathbb E}_W(X|\sigma(Y))=\{a\mapsto 2,b\mapsto 2,c\mapsto 4,d\mapsto 4,e\mapsto 6,f\mapsto 6\}$ is explicitly constructed as follows:

1. Construct the set of *atoms* ${\cal A}(Y) =\{\{x : Y(x) = a\}: a \in Y^{-1}(\Omega)\}$.
2. For each $A \in {\cal A}(Y)$, for each $a \in A$, set $Z(a) = \frac{{\mathbb E}_W(X\star {\mathbb 1}_A)}{{\mathbb P}(A)}$

In the example above, the atoms of ${\cal G}=\sigma(Y)$ are ${\cal A}(Y)=\{\{a,b\}, \{c,d\},\{e,f\}\}$ and ${\mathbb P}(A)=\frac{1}{3}$ for $A \in {\cal A}(Y)$. Also ${\mathbb E}_W(X\star {\mathbb 1}_{\{a,b\}})=\frac{2}{3}$,
${\mathbb E}_W(X\star {\mathbb 1}_{\{c,d\}})=\frac{4}{3}$ and
${\mathbb E}_W(X\star {\mathbb 1}_{\{e,f\}})=\frac{6}{3}$.  So for $a \in \{a,b\}$, $Z(a)=\frac{\frac{2}{3}}{\frac{1}{3}}=2$, and similarly for $\{c,d\}$ and $\{e,f\}$, so finally $Z=\{a\mapsto 2,b\mapsto 2,c\mapsto 4,d\mapsto5,e\mapsto 6,f\mapsto 6\}$.

**Conditional expectation: Explicit construction in continuous case**

Let $W=(\Omega,{\cal F},{\mathbb P})$ be the Brownian probability space.  Let ${\cal G} \subseteq {\cal F}$ be a sub-$\sigma$-algebra of ${\cal F}$.  Write $A_{\cal G}(\omega) \in {\cal G}$, for all $\omega \in \Omega$, for the *atom containing* $\omega$ in ${\cal G}$.  Then

$${\mathbb E}_W(X|{\cal G})(\omega)=\frac{{\mathbb E}_W(X\star {\mathbb 1}_{A_{\cal G}(\omega)})}{{\mathbb P}(A_{\cal G}(\omega))}$$

#### Natural filtration

Define the family of $\sigma$-algebras ${\cal F}_t$ for $t \geq 0$ by cylinder sets confined to times $0\leq s < t$ for some fixed $t$.  So ${\cal F}_s \subset {\cal F}_t \subset {\cal F}$ if $0 \leq s < t < \infty$.  We call ${\cal F}_t$ the *Brownian filtration* generated by the Brownian events up to time $t$.  Constructively, we can say that

$${\cal F}_t=\sigma(\{C(t_1,\ldots,t_n;I_1,\ldots,I_n): n \in {\mathbb Z}^+: 0\leq t_1<t_2<\cdots<t_n <t, I_k=(a_k,b_k),1\leq k \leq n\})$$

#### Original problem

Show, using the explicit construction of continuous conditional expectation, that for all $0\leq s \leq t$,  ${\mathbb E}_W(B_t|{\cal F}_s)(\omega)=B_s(\omega), 0\leq s\leq t$.  So, show that

$${\mathbb E}_W(B_t\star {\mathbb 1}_{A_{{\cal F}_s}(\omega)}) = B_s {\mathbb P}(A_{{\cal F}_s}(\omega))$$

Comment: Everytime you edit a post, it gets bumped up on the front page and crowds out other answers. If you want to compose a lengthy post requiring many edits, you might want to use the [sandbox on meta](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4666/sandbox-for-drafts-of-long-complex-posts).

Comment: Sorry I didn't know about that.  I'm not looking to crowd people out.  I am working on a question which may be trivial to the well-trained but is still foggy in my mind, and not of too much interest to others.  It's taking me a while to tease out all of the definitions to make the question well-posed and well-founded.

Comment: No problem, I just wanted to make you aware of the possibility to use the sandbox.